# How do i update UI in a method where i have widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, methods

Hod do i update the UI in a method or function in flutter, i have searched the internet for help and it seem that a callback function is a solution but i don't know how to implement this, Let me explain better my problem with my code block

I have a method :

```
void merchantDeatails(BuildContext ctx) {
    final controller = Get.find<HomeController>();
    showModalBottomSheet(
      elevation: 10,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: ctx,
      builder: (ctx) => Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(ctx).size.height * 0.5,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(30.0)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 11,
            ),
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 5,
                width: 40,
                child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Share',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Color(0xff263B4F),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.shortcut_outlined,
                        size: 25,
                        color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                        controller.isLiked.isTrue
                            ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                            : null;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: controller.isLiked.isFalse
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                              size: 22, color: Color(0xff34495E))
                          : Icon(
                              Icons.favorite_outlined,
                              size: 22,
                              color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                            ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

However when i tap the Gesture Detector, the Ui in the function is not updated, but other UI that has `isLiked` is updated.

How do i make setState to update the UI in this method?

```
setState(() {
                        controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                        controller.isLiked.isTrue
                            ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                            : null;
                      });
```

Comment: if **isLiked** boolean is declared by you and it is updated, call it inside the 
setState(() {
                       isLiked;
                        controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                        controller.isLiked.isTrue
                            ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                            : null;
                      });

Comment: @IspiderMalee hello sir, i want the UI in the function to rebuild just like a stateful widget so immediately i tap the icon, it will rebuild UI and change, this is not happening because it is inside a method, however tapping the icon set the state of other UI that `isLiked` is declared. I don't know if you understand my problem sir?

Comment: you can use `statefulBuilder` check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)

Comment: @SayyidJ This worked for me to change the state in the UI in the function, but when `isLiked` is changed to true with the setState in the function, i expect the UI in other stateful widget that has the `isLiked` to update instantly too. This is not happening. Do you have an idea why sir?

Comment: when you call `setState` inside statefulBuilder its refer to setState provided by its builder, if you want to call setState outside the builder, try rename the fuction given by the builder,  `(BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateMethod) { setStateMethod((){}) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are using GetX as a statemanagement tool so you need to use it instead of Stateful Widget.

in the toggle method of the GetXController you need to add **update();** line so GetX will update wherever you have used it's variable on other function or any method where you have GetBuilder Wrapped.

```
GetBuilder(
        init: HomeController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                        controller.isLiked.isTrue
                            ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                            : null;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: controller.isLiked.isFalse
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                              size: 22, color: Color(0xff34495E))
                          : Icon(
                              Icons.favorite_outlined,
                              size: 22,
                              color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                            ),
                    ),
                  ); } ),
```

Please look into GetBuilder functionality.

Comment: Thank you sir, his worked, although i changed `controller` in the builder function to `context` because for some reasons `controller` was causing me errors

Comment: you can use any name. Please use name "context" carefully